# SQL Service Reporting Service Account

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm new to SSRS.I have installed SQL Server and SSRS.

I'm trying to configure my Report Server , but it does not work.

It asks me for Username and password when I click on Reporting server web service URL in a web browser.

I tried my Windows username & password , but it doesn't work. I have installed SSRS in native mode.

Any input on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are running IE as Administrator if you are running it on the same machine that you have installed SSRS on. (Left click on IE icon in the Start Menu and select "Run as administrator")

Comment: @user1141584 If you found an answer useful, vote it up by clicking on the up arrow to the right of the answer. If your question was answered, then choose the correct/best/most helpful answer and "Accept" it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.